# Python time.sleep() not sleeping

Tags: python, time

I'm coding a game, and the fight function seems to be tripping me up. Here's the combat snippet of my code:

```
def combat(player, enemy, dun):
  print("\n"*100 + "A " + enemy.name + " has attacked you!")
  while player.health > 0 and enemy.health > 0:
    print(enemy.name[:1].upper() + enemy.name[1:], "health:", enemy.health)
    print("Your health:", player.health)
    cmd = input(">")
    if cmd == "attack":
      enemy.health -= player.atk(enemy)
    if cmd == "run":
      coin = random.choice(["heads", "tails"])
      if coin == "heads":
        break
      else:
        print("You couldn't escape.")
    if cmd == "equip":
      target = input("Which item?\n>")
      print(player.equip(target))
    player.health -= enemy.atk(player)

  if enemy.health <= 0:
    print("You defeated the", enemy.name + "!")
    if enemy.drop != None:
      return "Enemy defeated.\nThe " + enemy.name + " dropped a " + enemy.drop + "!"
      dun.data[dun.pos][2].append(enemy.drop)
    else:
      return "Enemy defeated."
    time.sleep(1.5)
    out = 1
  elif player.health <= 0:
    print("You died fighting %s..." % enemy.name)
    dun.pos == (0, 0)
    player.inventory == []
    return "You reawaken in the same room you started in, pack empty..."
    time.sleep(3)
```

I have imported the random module and the time module, it's just not in the snippet.

When the sequence ends, it does not sleep and goes right away into the main game loop (which I can give if needed).

Apart from being messy, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because you are returning before the `sleep` function call?

Comment: A decorator here would be useful, e.g @sleep_when_done(3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `return` statement immediately exits your function. Any code after it *will not run*. You can `sleep` before your `return`:

example:

```
time.sleep(1.5)
return "Enemy defeated."
```

But it probably makes a lot more sense to just sleep after you call your function:

```
combat(...)
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: This works, I did not realize that return ended immediately. Thank you very much.